# How do I clean those duplicates values that has different spellings in r?

Tags: r

How do I remove those duplicates that has different spellings?

Example table with duplicates

| Name | Score |
| --- | --- |
| Abi | 12 |
| Abby | 12 |
| Aby | 12 |
| Toom | 4 |
| Tom | 4 |
| Tm | 4 |
| Crow | 9 |

result I am looking for

| Name | Score |
| --- | --- |
| Abby | 12 |
| Tom | 9 |
| Crow | 4 |

```
name <- c('Abi', 'Abby', 'Aby', 'Toom', 'Tom', 'Tm', 'Crow')
score <- c(12,12,12,4,4,4,9)
duplicate <- data.frame(name,score)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
library(phonics)
keyname <-  c("Abby", "Tom", "Crow")
 duplicate %>%
    mutate(name2 = keyname[match(name, keyname)]) %>% 
    group_by(grp = soundex(name)) %>%
    mutate(name = name2[!is.na(name2)]) %>%
    ungroup %>% 
    distinct(name, score)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  name  score
  <chr> <dbl>
1 Abby     12
2 Tom       4
3 Crow      9
```

Answer (score 0):

With `adist`, you can group by string similarity:

```
nm <- c("Abby", "Tom", "Crow")
duplicate |>
  transform(name = nm[apply(adist(name, nm), 1, which.min)]) |>
  aggregate(score ~ name, FUN = mean)

  name score
1 Abby    12
2  Tom     4
3 Crow     9
```